# whats the different among Cocos2d's touch locationInView, covertToGL, and convertToNodeSpace？

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a beginner and confused with them. In console, their location have different values. So, what is the meaning of their own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

locationInView will give you the current location of the touch by the user according to normal cartesian co-ordinate system which is in portrait mode.

However, you need to convert those co-ordinates into OpenGL co-ordinates for getting the actual location. convertToGL just converts the co-ordinates into the current layout which maybe landscape mode or any other mode.

While, convertToNodeSpace will be used in, for example, tile-based games, where you have a big map. convertToNodeSpace will convert your openGL touch co-ordinates to the co-ordinates of the .tmx map or anything similar.

For example, consider following figure.
you maybe having a map of (1000,2000) size.

Now, when you touch the screen for the first time co-ordinates will be stored in normal portrait mode, which after converting into openGL will give you the correct co-ordinates on screen, say (100,100).
But your current location on map is (800,800). To get this location, u need convertToNodeSpace.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.I had tried in portrait mode and landscape mode, but they have nothing to do with locationInView and OpenGL.Maybe I understand incorrectly.

Comment: what i wanted to say is that when in landscape mode, cocos2d will consider the bottom left corner as origin i.e (0,0), while in simple iPhone programming,which you see in interface builder, the upper left corner will be considered as origin.

Comment: locationInView will give you the co-ordinates according to upper left origin, which you'll need to convert into the OpenGL co-ordinates to get the new co-ordinates.

Comment: @AkashThakkar : welcm to stack Overflow!

Comment: hi mj you are on which chat room pl send me the name of ur room and also give me the time at when you become online on Stack Overflow..

Comment: @AkashThakkar : naa re. Hu to gmail/fb par j hou chu. not on stacky